# JavaScript - A simple character count according to Twitter rules

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

I had to implement the remaining character count functionality (according to [Twitter](https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-length-ok-in-twitter-user-interface-but-too-long-through-api/24087/4) [rules](https://twittercommunity.com/t/update-api-counting-msg-length-incorrectly/55041)).

Can someone point me to JS library/function I can use directly?

Comment: Wait, so what are you asking? If you're looking to see how it can be improved try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Edited my original question according to what I exactly wanted - and I have already found the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter provide the [Twitter Text JavaScript library](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js) - it contains their official character count.

`twttr.txt.getTweetLength()` is the function you need.

Comment: Ok. I did not know we could call `getTweetLength()` function to achieve the same. Thanks.